# Can static variables be declared as private in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Applicant:
    applicant_id_count=1000
    application_dict={
                        "A":0,
                        "B":0,
                        "C":0
                     }
    def __init__(self,applicant_name):
        self.__applicant_name=applicant_name
        self.__applicant_id=None
        self.__job_band=None
```

I need to make the static variables in the above class i.e. `application_dict` and `applicant_id_count` as private static variables. Or is there any such thing in python?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python does not have access modifiers. If you want to access an instance (or class) variable from outside the instance or class, you are always allowed to do so.

That said there's a convention using underscores(_) that most developers follow to indicate that a variable/method is private. A single underscore is a convention of saying that it's a private variable but it actually doesn't change the access privilege. Example:

```
class Applicant:
    _applicant_id_count = 1000

Applicant._applicant_id_count # equals to 1000
```

If you want to emulate private variables for some reason, you can always use the `__` prefix. Python mangles the names of variables so that they're not **easily** visible. Example:

```
class Applicant:
    __applicant_id_count=1000
```

You will get the following error when someone tries to directly access it:

```
Applicant.__applicant_id_count
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class Applicant has no attribute '__applicant_id_count'
```

Someone can hack their way and use the variable like this:

```
Applicant._Applicant__applicant_id_count # prints out 1000
```

You can read more about it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/private-variables-python/

Answer (score 3):

In Python, you can always access all variables. But, there is a convention for naming of this classes and attributes. You can use the `__` prefix (two underscores) from [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Python mangles the names of variables like `__foo` so that they're not easily visible to code outside the class that contains them. Also, if you want a protected variable scope, you can use `_` prefix (one underscore).

Comment: From PEP 8: "Generally, double leading underscores should be used only to avoid name conflicts with attributes in classes designed to be subclassed."